# Floating point arithmetic: summation versus multiplication of error

Tags: floating-point, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand the floating point arithmetic behind this simple example. Both codes are arithmetically equivalent in theory, but obviously a series of additions adds more error than a simple multiplication.

```
s=0.0
for i in range(10):
    s += 0.1
print(s)
print('%.30f' % s)

0.9999999999999999
0.999999999999999888977697537484
```

but:

```
s=0.1
s *= 10
print(s)
print('%.30f' % s)
1.0
1.000000000000000000000000000000
```

I would like to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

I understand that the binary representation of the decimal 0.1 is never accurate, and that can be verified by:

```
print(0.1)
print('%.30f' % 0.1)
0.1
0.100000000000000005551115123126
```

So in a sequence of summations, that remainder `5.55e-18` keeps adding up to the variable and very quickly it grows.

However, when multiplying, I'd expect that the same remainder is also multiplied and it would grow, but that doesn't happen. Why is that? Any sort of optimisation before converting to binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just has to do with how results are rounded (internally, in binary). 0.1 [converts to](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)

`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`

which is

`0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101` [in binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/).

[Multiply that](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-calculator/) by 10 (1010 in binary) and you get

```
1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

That is 55 significant bits; rounded to 53 bits it equals 1.0.

Add 0.1 ten times and you'll go through a sequence of roundings (your assumption that the error "keeps adding up to the variable and very quickly it grows" is wrong -- why would adding 0.1 ten times be *less than* 1.0 then?). If you print the full decimal values after each iteration and you should see

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
0.5
0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125
0.899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
```

Look at what happens between 0.5 and 0.6, for example. Add the internal binary values for 0.5 and 0.1

`0.1` + `0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101`

The answer is

```
0.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

That is 55 bits; rounded to 53 bits it's

```
0.10011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

which in decimal is

0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375

which is less than 0.6, though you might have expected it to be greater.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. It makes sense now.

Comment: May be worth adding that the rounding to 53 bits has to do with IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic. [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error]