# Incrementing by < 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I've just been experimenting with for loops and noticed this when I changed the increment value to `i += 0.1`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 0.1) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

In the console it returns

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
```

By the time you reach 100

```
99.69999999999861
99.7999999999986
99.8999999999986
99.9999999999986
```

What is the reason behind this?
I imagine this would be frustrating if you are trying to search for a number. Is there a way to round to the nearest 10th? I know how to round with `Math.floor, ~~, a | 0`, but only to the nearest whole integer.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: What is your real problem? and please read [floating-point tag kiwi](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info)

Comment: First I've ever heard of 'floating point precision'. Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737008/floating-point-arithmetic-summation-versus-multiplication-of-error/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 0.1) {
    console.log(Math.round(i * 100) / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Multiply by ten, add one, divide by ten.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i = (i * 10 + 1) / 10) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i = (i * 10 + 1) / 10) {
      console.log(i);
    }
```

Comment: Multiplying an imprecise value by 10 doesn't make it more precise. Better avoid floating point calculation as far as possible. `for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { console.log(i / 10.0); }`

Comment: You are not multiplying an "imprecise" floating point  value by 10, but rather  multiplying an integer by 10 and adding 1 and finally dividing by 10, to avoid the alternative, which is adding 0.1. With the former, you are performing integer addition and then dividing by ten to produce a float (which is precise enough for the purpose of answering this question). With latter, you are directly adding floats, which is not precise enought.